# How to get around Run-time Error 1004

Tags: vba, file, xlsx

I am attempting copying multiply .csv files into a single .xlsx file. However, the files are rather large (400,000 rows) and after a few seconds I get a Run time Error 1004.

My code for copying the files is below. Supposedly by saving the file periodically during the write process this error is supposed to be fixed, but I'm not sure how to do that. Would it be better to just put each file in its own sheet?

```
Dim x As Variant
Dim Cnt As Long, r As Long, c As Long

FilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
file = Dir(FilePath & "*.csv")
Do While Len(file) > 0
    Cnt = Cnt + 1
    r = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Open FilePath & file For Input As #1     
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, strData
            x = Split(strData, ",")
            For c = 0 To UBound(x)
                Cells(r, c + 1).Value = Trim(x(c))
            Next c
            r = r + 1
        Loop
    Close #1
    file = Dir
Loop
If Cnt = 0 Then MsgBox "No CSV files found...", vbExclamation
```

It gives the error on the line: `Cells(r, c + 1).Value = Trim(x(c))`

It appears that this code is copying all the rows to the same row in the output file and that it stops when it reaches the maximum number of columns. (The .csv files are 32 columns.)

Comment: If you add a breakpoint, which line gives the error?  There is a limit to the number of columns (and rows) that can be written to but columns is less.  If you want to save periodically, you can add a `ActiveWorkbook.Save` but it should be possible to find the actual error and fix it.

Comment: @Byron I edited my question to include the line on which the error ocurred.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: what values are reported in the watch window for those variables when the error occurs?  Trying to see if you have too many rows/columns or are somehow causing an error with the call to `Trim`

Comment: Ok. The code took like 6 minutes to run last time before it died so it might be a second. :)

Comment: here are instructions on how to save/close: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210684

Comment: @Byron c=16384, r=2, x(c)="0"

Comment: You have too many columns.  `c` is right at the limit.  [Check out MS support on the topic](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).  If you need that many columns, then you will have to split it up somehow.

Comment: @Byron Weird. My .csv files are only 32 columns wide. Also I just noticed all the data went into the first row in the output file.

Comment: It's likely that your data has a bunch of commas in it then.  `Split` is a dumb function so I would check how your data is formatted.  It is seeing 16,000 commas somehow.  Maybe the line breaks between rows are not being picked up correctly?

Comment: @Byron The data is purely numerical except for the first row which are words. (With all spaces replaced by underscores.)

Comment: Then check out what is stored in `strData`... it might be missing the line breaks and running all the rows into a single row with `400,000*32` columns!

Comment: If the files are all csv files, you could try using `Workbooks.Open`. It will be much faster than reading the files one line at a time.

Comment: @Byron when the code fails, strData contains only a portion of the title row for one of the files. (It cut off half way through a word.) It doesn't hold the entire row for some reason. Could it be too long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I was unable to get the code working so I switched to a different method using [Query Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837764.aspx). This copied the data MUCH faster (6 seconds compared to 6 minutes.)

```
i = 0
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path)
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If Right$(objFile, 3) = "csv" Then
        Sheets(i + 1).Cells.Clear 'remove for final release possibly?
        With Sheets(i + 1).QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" + objFile, Destination:=Sheets(i + 1).Range("A1"))
            .Name = objFile
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = 3
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        End With
        i = i + 1
    End If
    Set objFile = Nothing
Next objFile
```

Comment: Some code would be nice.  Did you verify why the above method did not work?  Did your data have stray commas in it? ... or was there something going on with the lines?

Comment: @Byron I have no idea why my old code didn't work. I added my working code.